# Loading a gif from URL in Processing with gifAnimation Library

Tags: image, url, processing, gif

I am currently trying to load a gif into a processing sketch from a url. I am using the [gifAnimation library](https://github.com/extrapixel/gif-animation) and when I load a gif stored on my computer it works fine. I just cant seem to get it when I load from url, nothing shows up. Currently I can load the first frame using default Processing like this:

```java
webGif= loadImage(url, "gif");
image(webGif,0,0,720,720);
```

If I try and load a gif using the library from the url

```java
webGif= new Gif(this, url);
image (webGif, 0 , 0);
webGif.loop();
```

It doesn't load anything and my program freezes.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of disconnected code snippets.

Comment: That is all that is needed to produce my problem. Just replace "url" with a gif url.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a gif from URL seems to work as expected:

```
import gifAnimation.*;

Gif loopingGif;
public void setup() {
  size(400, 200);
  frameRate(100);

  loopingGif = new Gif(this, "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/1f/d4/83/1fd4831252c28010546e872d5b85bb70.gif");
  loopingGif.loop();
}

void draw() {
  background(255 / (float)height * mouseY);
  image(loopingGif, 10, height / 2 - loopingGif.height / 2);
}
```

tested with gifAnimation 3.1 using Processing 3.2.3

Also double check the URL is valid and the file is a valid gif, before checking Processing and library versions.